# Unable to find locator for auto complete options for "flying from" field

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

URL: https://www.wakanow.com/en-ng/

Type mum in Flying from text box. It shows suggestions. I want to print all options but unable to find locator for the same because html is hiding on mouse click.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the parent element, id txt-modi-fly-from, and select "Break on ... Subtree modifications".

You'll find that when you enter 'mum' into the field, the javascript on page will freeze. Keep pressing the Resume button on the far right until your expected entries are visible.

It appears you can do a findElement by ID 'txt-modi-fly-from_dropdown', then findElements by classname 'angucomplete-row'.